# Model.updateAttribute is not updating anything

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm trying to update an attribute but it doesn't change at all

I've tried with upsertWithWhere with no luck

I have this model

```
{
  "name": "worker",
  "plural": "workers",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "company-name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "orderId": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  }
```

and when i create a new instance I have this

```
{ name: 'trabajador',
  'company-name': 'ibm',
  email: 'e@mail.com',
  id: 1 }
```

But when I try to update it with this function

```
await Worker.findOne({where: {id:workerId}}).then(res => {
                if (!res) { throw "There are no workers with Id " + workerId }
                console.log(res)
                res.updateAttribute({orderId: orderId}).then(res => {console.log(res)}).catch(err => {throw err})
            }).catch(err => {throw err})
```

It doesn't do anything. It returns the same instance without the wanted orderId attribute.

I expect the output to be something like

```
{ name: 'trabajador',
  'company-name': 'ibm',
  email: 'e@mail.com',
  id: 1,
  orderId: 1
 }
```

but instead i get it without the ***orderId***

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
res.updateAttribute('orderId', orderId); // one attribute
```

or

```
res.updateAttributes({orderId: orderId}); // multiple attributes
```